# HTML 5 Audio to play MP3 in Internet Explorer 8,9,10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, html5-audio

I have tested the following code in Chrome and it works a treat, but Internet explorer doesn't seem to start playing the sound (I am testing in IE9).  The rest endpoints returns a data stream with audio/mp3 audio/aac audio/ogg mime types as appropriate...

```
var url = "/MyServer/services/rest/notifications/sounds/"+soundId+"/"+soundFormat;
var snd = new Audio(url);

snd.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if (this.debug) {
        console.info("Sound ended");
    }
    that.playingSound = false;
});

if (this.debug) {
    console.info("Requesting sound to start url:"+url);
}

that.playingSound = true;

snd.play();
```

Any ideas what might get IE working?  I've seen some HTML 5 capability tables that say this is not supported in IE9, whereas other places imply it should work?  Maybe this only works if you use the embedded HTML tags instead of code (with preload true), however I need to dynamically load the sound at runtime.

Comment: All I can say from the top of my head is that it's not going to work in IE8, it should work in IE9 and 10, but I am not in the mood to reboot to windows to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Internet Explorer are behind the times, if you can only use HTML5 to achieve what you're after, than IE 7,8,9 are pretty much useless as they barely, if at all, support HTML5. If you really want it to work in IE than you'll have to use a HTML4 solution.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589489(v=vs.85).aspx

And what Dominic B-c said isn't exactly right at all, IE9 supports a fair number of html5 features. Far less still than the others, but developers have trouble acknowledging the many features (like mp3 playing) they did add. Btw, that page seems to be using an audio element rather than an audio object, that might be the difference.